# Новое значение переменной с помощью eval()

Tags: javascript

Привет.

У нас имеется переменная:

```
var str_1234 = 'Hello';
```

Я пытаюсь присвоить ей новое значение таким способом:

```
eval('str_' + '1234') = 'Goodbye';
```

Но выдаёт ошибку. Дело в том, что цифры 1234, приходят с сервера. Мы заведомо не знаем какие цыфры придут. Поэтому я решил воспользоваться подобным способом. Как мне присвоить новое значение для переменной?

Comment: Задавал [похожий вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/355825/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-eval), немного в другом контексте.

Answer (score 1):

> Дело в том, что цифры 1234, приходят с сервера

запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым не нужна

> цыфры

эй, ну в прошлый раз же через "и" было написано, что за дела?

> Как мне присвоить новое значение для переменной?

Через eval (плохой метод)

```
eval('var str_' + data + ' = \'Goodbye\'); // Удивительно, правда?
```

Выставляя глобальную переменную (плохой метод, да и нода какая-нибудь вряд ли знает про window)

```
window['str_' + data] = 'Goodbye';
```

Выставляя значение в текущем контексте (опасно и некрасиво)

```
this['str_' + data] = 'Goodbye';
```

Правильней всего, однако, просто завести объект.

```
var data = {};
data['str_' + suffix] = 'Goodbye';
```

Несмотря на то, что он сам по себе не является контекстом, его легко можно использовать как контекст, а также передавать куда угодно (объекты передаются по ссылке, поэтому переданный куда-то объект будет по факту все тем же объектом, и изменения будут происходить синхронно во всех контекстах).

Answer (score 1):

C eval, который никто не рекомендует:

```
eval('str_' + '1234 = '+'Goodbye');
```

Без eval:

```
window['str_' + '1234'] = 'Goodbye';
```

---

Причина ошибки в том, что код переданный в eval выполняется, но сама функция никаких значений не возвращает и вместо себя не подставляет. Получается, вы присваиваете ничему какое-то значение.